# Openshift baremetal install vs cloud (Openstack IaaS) and node count

Tags: openstack, openshift-origin, openshift-online-3

We are looking at installing Openshift and have the choice of installing on baremetal (64 physical nodes) or Openstack (IaaS consisting of 64 physical nodes).

We are trying to work out the advantages of baremetal vs IaaS (assuming the same hardware profile of both environments)

The main obvious difference seems to be the Openshift node count. Baremetal will always be 1:1, so a maximum of say 60 nodes, however cloud deployments on Openstack can scale Openshift nodes massively as they are just instances.

Does the ability to scale Openshift nodes on Openstack actually matter as you are always limited to the physical resource available underneath anyway, so this should this not be a reason alone for selecting an IaaS Openshift install over baremetal?

Comment: Virtlualizing gives you so much more flexibility that I'd just do that anyway. Of course you should not have 1:1 virtual-physical machines. This negates many of the advantages!

Comment: There are problems with virtualising with Openstack - another layer of complexity to manage, double network encapsulation (means slower networking), more fault domains (baremetal, IaaS (Openstack) and CaaS (Openshift), more complex upgrade paths/dependancies, less visibility of pod to baremetal relationship (more detached)

Answer (score 0):

After some research the answer is twofold -

1. **Configuration maximums vs resource availability vs pod demand**

   (*from RH Openshift 3.9*)

   - Maximum nodes per cluster 2000
   - Maximum pods per cluster 120,000
   - Maximum pods per node 250
   - Maximum pods per core 10

     If in the unlikely situation you have a small amount of physical
     nodes and a very high pod requirement it may push you towards a
     cloud IaaS (Openstack) as the install base to increase the node
     count.
2. **The management overhead Openstack brings**

   If for example you are have the choice of using a third party
      managed Openstack cloud this may be appealing for the flexibility
      and API richness this brings to complement Openshift, without any of
      the Openstack operational fuss. Caveats may be performance
      compromises based on nested network overlays and virtualisation in
      general.

   For my situation with 64 physical nodes available the
   baremetal Openshift deployment will be plenty enough to meet the
   required node count for our pod requirements and will give maximum
   performance and operational ease.